# Python - How to save lines from python36 command line to a .py file?

Tags: python, file, save

There is a CMD-like tool for python, python36.
Where if you type a line and press enter you get the output.
I want to save whatever I wrote there into a file with the ending .py, how can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Copy and pasta?

Answer (score 2):

**A simple demo code:**

```
with open("output.py","w") as fp:
    while True:
        line = input("please input:")
        if line == "": # press enter to exit
            break
        fp.write(line+"\n")
```